# Set HTTP ResponseTypes for whole class instead of for each method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, swagger

In an ASP.NET MVC project, we have several endpoint methods where some of the tags are set for all methods, such as the `ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)` tag.

Is there a way to set some response for all methods in the class?

As you can see four lines of code are used for only the status codes

```
/// <summary> A summary describing the endpoint</summary>
[HttpPost("RenameSomething/", Name = "Rename[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK),
 ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound),
 ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest),
 ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
public ActionResult RenameSomething()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply such [`ProducesResponseType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesresponsetypeattribute) attribute on your controller class,
since this attribute can be applied on both a method or a class as specified by its `AttributeUsage`.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(  
    System.AttributeTargets.Class |  
    System.AttributeTargets.Method,  
    AllowMultiple=true, Inherited=true
    )]
public class ProducesResponseTypeAttribute : Attribute
```

---

```
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK),
    ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound),
    ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest),
    ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    ]
public class MyController : Controller
{
}
```

---

To take this even further, you can go for a [convention based approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions), but that looks like more than you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is great, I'm already implementing. Is it safe to assume that method tag `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<SomethingDto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)` will overrige class tag `[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]`?

Comment: @jonadv As far as I know/remember, the attributes on class level are added up with those on method level.